# Search mails with attachment that are not signatures

Tags: thunderbird, search

If I use the Quick Select functionality in Thunderbird to show only messages with an attachment, I get also shown all messages that have a PGP signature as attachment.

This is totally useless for me, Is there an option to blacklist those signatures and show only mails with real attachments?

Answer (score 0):

Old: While the "quick select" doesn't necessarily have the strict search criteria you're looking for, you might try doing the search and then sorting by file size. Those signatures are rarely larger than a few KB, and I'm assuming the files you'd be looking for would drastically dwarf the signatures in comparison.

New: The optimal method for achieving the methods required (retrieve items that have attachments that are not signature and are retrievable by date) is to use the Thunderbird's "Saved Search Folder" functionality.

Going to Edit> Find> Search Messages, and defining multiple sets of criteria, then clicking the button for "Save as Search Folder" will allow a return of those items, searchable as a normal inbox.

Image of my search criteria: https://i.stack.imgur.com/akANI.png

Comment: That would be a workaround, but not perfect. I would loose the possibility to search those files by date also, Or is there a soloution to search for only mails with an attachment and with a minimum size?

Comment: An understandable need, to be sure. Have you tried any third-party addons? The addon located at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/totalquickfilter/ allows for filtering by more than one criteria, which may give you what you need (actually, it may give you more than you want!)

Comment: Can you give me a specific revision for your v31 (eg. 31.1.1)? I'll try and duplicate the scenario you're in to see if there's a valid solution.

Comment: That addon doesn't seem to work correctly on TB 31.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit) with Unity: I don't get any results anymore if I try to narrow the search with this plugin enabled. Anyway it wouldnt allow to search for email size anyway

Comment: You are very correct. The addon I suggested doesn't help, however I did find that Thunderbird has functionality for a "Saved Search Folder." I'm editing my answer to include the steps for that.